# Action of $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, covering-spaces

Is there a connection between Artin-Schreier theorem on finite groups which can be absolute Galois groups and the classification of finite groups freely acting on even-dimensional sphere?

The former says that all finite extensions $[E:F]<\infty$ with $E$ algebraically closed are $E=F[\sqrt {-1}]$, so the only finite absolute Galois group is $\mathbb Z_2$.

The latter says that the only finite group that can freely act on even-dimensional sphere is also $\mathbb Z_2$, by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.

Comment: There's also only one one-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Z_2$, only one group of order $2$, only one group with a trivial automorphism group, et cetera. What makes you think there's a connection beyond the words "only" and the presence of the group $\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: @Adam Hughes: One can reformulate the second fact using function fields instead of varieties, then in both cases there is a nice enough action of finite group on a field.

Comment: @se0808, the second fact involves spheres and is an eminently *topological* fact: how do you propose to get a true reformulated statement with functions fields involved?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I supposed to consider it as real affine algebraic variety, to take a function field and, maybe, to use Lefschetz fixed point theorem in other setting.

Comment: But none of the fields in your question has to be related to $\mathbb R$ in any sensible way. (If you want to assume that $F=\mathbb R$, then the argument I sketched in my answer actually *does* work)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I just meant that maybe they are two pieces of more abstract picture, like with coverings and Galois theory. And thank you!

Comment: The only finite group that can act freely on an EVEN-dimensional sphere is $\Bbb Z/2$. There is some obvious thing to be said in terms of the different Galois theories of field extensions and covering spaces. In particular if $S\rightarrow M$ is a universal covering of (even dimensional $\ne 4$) manifolds of finite degree, then the degree is necessarily $2$. Of course, this statement requires the Poincare conjecture in these dimensions. If nothing else, this statement seems to sound like Artin-Schreier even if the actual mathematics behind it is not as closely related.

Comment: Include "with appropriate integral homology" in the appropriate place in my last comment.

Comment: Asked again on MathOverflow, see [MO:253403](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253403/).

Answer (score 3):

**An idea.**

If $E/F$ is a finite extension, then we can construct the projective space $P_FE$ corresponding to $E$ viewed as an $F$-vector space. The multiplication on $E$ induces an abelian group structure on $P_FE$, which turns it into an algebraic group defined over $F$.

I seriouly doubt there are many abelian group structures on projective spaces (this should be proved by looking at the cohomology) so this has to restrict at least the degree of the extension. After this, we are left with a projective space with dimeension in a very small set and on which a finite group acts in a rather special way, and *hand waving* will show that the order of the group is $2$.

*Remark.* If we take $F=\mathbb R$, then $P_FE$ is a real projective space and a compact abelian real Lie group, and we can consider them as smooth manifolds. The latter means it is a real torus, and as no positive dimensional projective space is a a torus (this is can be checkd looking at the de Rham cohomology of these manifolds) we conclude that $\dim P_FE=0$, that is, that $\dim_FE=2$. The extension is therefore quadratic, and we did not need any fixed point theorem.

Comment: A similar argument does prove that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed; there, the key point is that projective complex algebraic groups are tori (this is a Lie theoretical fact), and no tori is a projective space (this can be proved by looking at the cohomology of tori and projective spaces)